# Is it possible to break code-behind into multiple partial files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, coding-style, webforms

I have a .aspx Web Form with a .aspx.cs code-behind.  The code-behind is nearly 2000 lines long, and it's getting to the point where the only way to easily navigate it is to put a ton of spaces in between the sections, zoom out so I can see the physical look of the code, and then zoom in where I want to edit.  In other words, it's a major pain.  I'd like to split this 2000 line into different files that represent concepts in the code.  So when I need to go edit some functionality in the "Employee" jquery tab of the page, I can just go to the partial class that contains just the "Employee" functionality.

In the New Item menu, I cannot find anything for an additional code-behind file, no .aspx.cs file.  I tried creating a .cs file, renaming it to .aspx.cs, and giving it the same partial class name --- no go, I couldn't see any of the methods of the default partial class, nor the controls on the page.

I understand the concept that if your "class", in the OOP sense, is that long, it's doing too much.  What I don't understand is a "class" in terms of code-behind for a web form.  The form can't really be broken down into smaller forms --- the user experience needs to all take place on one page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). So add a new `.cs` file to your project and use a partial class.

For example assuming you currently have the following `Default.aspx.cs` file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ... some 2000 lines of code
}
```

you could add another .cs file to your project in which:

```
public partial class _Default
{
    ... a subset of the 2000 lines of code could be moved here
        in order to isolate some functionality
}
```

It's very important that this partial class is declared in exactly the same namespace as the original class and has the same name.

But note that using partial classes only hides the shit. It doesn't clean it. If you want to clean it you will have to consider OOP practices to split functionality in different classes. You should layer your application.

Comment: ...but that makes me sad inside.

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I was trying earlier, but I must have been doing something wrong --- I wasn't able to see the methods in the other file :)  Works like a charm now though.  Sadly though, the application is already layered.  This code-behind is just to accommodate for the user interface, which is kind of heavy because we're using JQuery tabs, and the content of each tab is a whole beast in and of itself.  Sound advice though, thanks.

Comment: If you think 2000 is a lot, try 20,000. That's right, twenty thousand lines in a single code-behind file. You can imagine the difficulty in maintaining this class in one file. The real answer is of course to refactor this completely, but as a stop-gap measure, partial class files may be the answer in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The use or partial classes will solve the generic problem that you are looking into. There is another way that you can manage your code by using region tags within your code, so that you can open and close regions of code.

Example:

```
    #region isntances

    public StreamWriter LogFile;
    public FileStream fs;
    string _RunID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


    #endregion
```

This will allow you to mark up your code to track through it better.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
Ctrl-M, Ctrl-O
```

followed by

```
Ctrl-M, Ctrl-L
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me a trick even if its kinda pointless to the question.